# Angular 2 *ngIf not reevaluation on model change

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a navbar with 2 buttons. I wish to only show the button for the other page and disable the button for the current page.

On opening the settings page, the settings button is hidden. When I click the profile button, it doesn't disable and settings button doesn't appear.

Here's the component class code:

```html
export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {
   isSettingsProfile = false;
   isSettingsHome = false;
   
   ngOnInit() {
       this.isSettingsHome = true;
       this.isSettingsProfile = false;
   }
   
   OnNavBarClick(button: string) {
       if (button = "settings") {
           console.log ('setting home true/ profile false')
           this.isSettingsHome = true;
           this.isSettingsProfile = false;
       }
       else if (button = "profiles") {
           console.log ('setting home false/ profile true')
           this.isSettingsProfile = true;
           this.isSettingsHome = false;
       }
       
   }
```

And the navbar html:

```html
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li> <a [routerLink]="['/home']" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li *ngIf="!isSettingsHome" class="active"><a [routerLink]="['/settings']" href="#" (click)="OnNavBarClick('settings')">Settings</a></li>
            <li *ngIf="!isSettingsProfile"><a [routerLink]="['/settings/profile']" href="#" (click)="OnNavBarClick('profile')">Profile</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer is right, you have an extra quote. However, if that was just a typeo when you brought the code over, then there may be another solution. You could try and call a function in your AngularJS class that returns its value, like so: `return this.isSettingsHome;`

Comment: `if (button = "settings")` should be `if (button === "settings")`.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue when implementing a breadcrumb component and have applied the solution proposed [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755184/ngif-not-detecting-var-change). I had to change to

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

because I use angular4 and then call

> detectChanges()

at the end of your function OnNavBarClick()

Comment: missing code `constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,..` then `this.cd.detectChanges()`. It might a obvious to angular developper, but not when you are only on maintenance of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You have a redundant `"` in  `<li *ngIf="!isSettingsHome"" class`

Comment: It could be that the router destroys the component on click and the click handler doesn't get a chance to update or it might update but the component is recreated when you navigate back. Hard to see from the code you provided. Please create a Plunker that allows to reproduce.

Comment: You might want to **not** make the `<a>`  a `routerLink` and instead call `this.router.navigate(['/settings'])` in `OnNavbarClick()`

Comment: I may be dense, but the navigation works perfectly, just the buttons don't show correctly.  I guess I'm not going to worry about it.... just show which is active at the time.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hard to tell. Without seeing the context where the component and the template is used I can't tell anything. I haven't yet tried to change the state in the component at the same time as navigating away.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going on here, and can't be without knowing more about your router structure, but I think gunter is likely correct that the navigation is causing the component to reload and thus reverting the component to it's initial state.  I will recommend the following restructure:

First, add the routerLinkActive directive to your router links and set the class to "hide-link" (or whatever name you prefer)

```
 <li><a [routerLink]="['/settings']" routerLinkActive="hide-link">Settings</a></li>
```

then define a simple CSS class to hide the link

```
.hide-link { display: none; }
```