# ngIf not detecting var change

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using the *greensock animation library* to animate some components (as you would expect). I am experiencing an issue when I am updating a variable in the `onComplete` function which is bound to a `*ngIf`. For some reason, angular is not detecting the update to the variable in the callback.

---

**Intended functionality:**

```
1. click grey image.
2. pink image fades out
3. one of the grey images dissapears.
```

**Current functionality:**

```
1. click grey image.
2. pink image fades out
3. (nothing happens)
4. click grey image - again.
5. one of the grey images dissapears.
```

---

I have a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZubdejwQ3RmLKBxE1ebX?p=preview) for the following...

```
declare var TweenMax; // defined in index.html
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <img *ngIf="leftVisible" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" (click)="animate(-1)"/>
    <img *ngIf="rightVisible" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" (click)="animate(1)"/>
    <img #otherImage src="http://placehold.it/350x150/ff00ff/000000"/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild('otherImage') otherImageElement;

  private leftVisible: boolean;
  private rightVisible: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.leftVisible = this.rightVisible = true;
  }

  private animate(_direction: number){
    var tween = TweenMax.to(this.otherImageElement.nativeElement, 1, {
      opacity: 0,
      onComplete: () => {
        console.log("anim complete");
        this.rightVisible = false;
      }
    }
  };
}
```

You can see in the console that the callback fires successfully and updates the variable, however the element which is bound to the `*ngIf` does not change **until you click one of the grey images a second time**.

How do I get this to update as intended in the `onComplete` callback?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

please refer to this Angular 2 documentation: [Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

According to the documentation,

> Angular's unidirectional data flow rule forbids updates to the view after it has been composed. Both of these hooks fire after the component's view has been composed.

**Option1:** use `ngZone.run` to notify angular to render the view again.

```
// import ngZone from @angular/core first.
this.ngZone.run(() => {
  console.log("anim complete");
  this.rightVisible = false;
});
```

**Option2:** use `ChangeDetector` to let angular to render the view again.

```
import {ChangeDetector} from '@angular/core';

this.rightVisible = false;
this.cd.detectChanges();
```

Refer this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Kafzw30vdqXK9Gvcamf1?p=preview) that contains the upper code block.

Comment: Your link does not reference lifecycle hooks.

Comment: @lhunath sorry for that, link has been fixed.

Comment: I am using angular 6 and am having the same issue. I tried both suggestions with no luck. Any idea why? @Pengyy