# Angular 2 expression has changed after it was checked error as a result of scrollbar being added

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a getter function which returns the offsetWidth of part of a component. At some point the page populates with elements triggering a scrollbar to be added to the page. The scrollbar addition changes the layout of the page by a few pixels, and changes the width of my component which is set as `width:100%` in CSS. The layout change apparently occurs within the change detection cycle.

The problem is that my getter function then returns a different value because it's width has indeed changed along with the page layout change, and triggers the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError.

Here is my function:

```
get width() {
    return this.track.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
}
```

What is a way I can sidestep or suppress this error?

Comment: I think if you calculate width in `ngOnInit` to a `var` and then reference this in your html as `[style.width]='varName'` then you won't receive this error. You could also try using `ngZone` which worked for me in a kind of similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755184/ngif-not-detecting-var-change

Comment: I have to account for user resizing of the window, so storing it in a variable wouldn't really work for me. I'm not sure where/how I would apply ngZone in this scenario.