# angular html not updating

Tags: angular, typescript, change-detector-ref

I'm trying to update component.html according to a value that sent from the service.

In service.ts:

```
public loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
generateDoc(): void {
    this.loggedIn.next(true);
    //function body here - it takes few seconds
    this.loggedIn.next(false);
```

component.ts:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core'; 
async ngOnInit() {
    this.reportService.loggedIn.subscribe(response => {
    this.isDownload = response; 
    this.cd.markForCheck();
    console.log(`is download value changed! ${this.isDownload}`)}); }
```

component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="isDownload">
wait...</div>
```

The variable value is updated in the ts - I can see it in the console, but the HTML not updated no matter what I'm trying.
with `this.cd.detectChanges` only the HTML changed when the value is true and do nothing when it false

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: @j.hersh I think here's the solution you need  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755184/ngif-not-detecting-var-change

Comment: You sent `true` and `false` to loggedIn obs. But JS is synchronous, so the obs could receive the two values in few nanoseconds (not enough to see an effect)

Comment: @CristianTraìna  thanks, but it takes a few seconds..

Comment: Please elaborate, why is your ngOnInit async? Do you have any await in it? async ngOnInit is a bad practice and should be avoided, it could also have impact on your issue.

Comment: @j.hersh doesn't matter. Check how JS events loop works :)

Comment: Events are queued and they are executed when there is nothing to do. So no matter "when" you scheduled the events (calling next)

Comment: `<div *ngIf="service.loggedIn | async">You are logged in.</div>` is the way to go.